# Changing Style with Jquery

Tags: jquery, styles

```
<style>

  .ui-autocomplete.' . "$name"  . ' .ui-menu-item
  {
      font-size: 10px;
      width: auto;
  }

</style>
```

Where name is the attribute name of a input.

What is the jquery equivalent code of  the above code?

Comment: Are you trying to ask how to apply the class using jquery?

Comment: You want jQuery to create a custom selector, to give `.ui-autocomplete[name=elementNameAttribute].ui-menu-item`, in your style element? Or you want to style the elements, with jQuery, that match that selector?

Comment: I want to style the elements, with jQuery, that match that selector

Answer (score 0):

maybe will be:

$(".ui-autocomplete.'."$name".'.ui-menu-item").css({ '.$item_style.'})